# How to draw a rectangle a the map using C#?

Tags: arcobjects, arcmap, c#

I have two points, `Ipoint upperRight;` and `Ipoint lowerLeft;` points.

from the previous points i can get the *height* and the *width* for the rectangle.

How can i draw a rectangle on the map?.

I think i should use `IGraphicsContainer.AddElement` Method, but i don't know how, i searched through the internet but didn't find any useful example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the code to draw a rectangle to page layout view.

```
IEnvelope env = element.Geometry.Envelope;
```

---

```
if (env != null) {
IPageLayout pLayout = activeView as IPageLayout;
IGraphicsContainer graphicsContainer = pageLayout as IGraphicsContainer;
graphicsContainer.Reset();
IRectangleElement rectangleElement = new RectangleElementClass();
IElement elem = rectangleElement as IElement;
elem.Geometry = env;
graphicsContainer .AddElement(elem, 0);
activeView.PartialRefresh(esriViewDrawPhase.esriViewGraphics, null, null);
}
```