# How to get 'IGraphicsContainer' from the map?

Tags: arcobjects, arcmap

I tried to get `IGraphicsContainer` from Data View (active map) using `FocusMap`, `ActiveView`

```
IGraphicsContainer graphicsContainer = (IGraphicsContainer)neApp.Document.MxDocument.FocusMap;
```

but the variable always null, is there any different way to do this?

---

I already get from page layout view in this question right here:
[Get IGraphicsContainer from page layout](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/43341/how-to-draw-a-rectangle-a-the-map-using-c)
but i need it from data view (map).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [Map](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/arcobjects-net/componenthelp/index.html#/MapClass_Class/001200000s13000000/) class does implement [IGraphicsContainer](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/arcobjects-net/componenthelp/index.html#/IGraphicsContainer_Interface/0012000005p0000000/), so most likely the problem is in the expression `neApp.Document.MxDocument.FocusMap`. Make sure it does not return `null`.

Also be aware that a map can contain multiple graphic layers. See the discussion in [IMap.BasicGraphicsLayer](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/arcobjects-net/componenthelp/index.html#/BasicGraphicsLayer_Property/001200000m8t000000/) documentation for details.

Comment: Thanks, can you know how to change the view from layout view to data view see this question, http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/43593/move-to-data-view-from-layout-view