# How to change the view from layout view to data view using c# code in ArcMap?

Tags: arcobjects, arcmap, c#

How to change the view from *layout view* to *data view* using c# code?

---

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use the [IMxDocument.ActiveView](http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/componenthelp/index.html#/ActiveView_Property/000v00000113000000/) Property.

You can use something like this:

```
IMxDocument mxDoc=(IMxDocument)m_app.Document;
mxDoc.ActiveView = mxDoc.FocusMap ; //if you want to cast to the focused map
```

Comment: When i run the code it's work fine but when i want to get back to layout view (not code) the arcMap stop working. and there is no exception. i don't know why.

Comment: @IbrahimSwaiss I'm not sure why, but activating the View is causing the problem. Just use the first two lines. It is working on my system.

Comment: Yes it's now working, and you can use Deactivate() after the activate line, and thank you again for your help :)

Comment: The docs state that you do not need to call Activate() inside ArcMap, it will take care of that automatically. You only need to call Activate in certain situations when working with MapDocument class.